# Ubuntu 20.04.04 LTS stuck on black screen and flashing cursor after first install (sudo apt-get update doesn't work too)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, grub2, uefi

## The Problem

I got a new laptop (HP Victus 16.1) and tried installing Ubuntu on it. After instillation and restart, I do not get the usual "remove download media" but instead get sent to the GNU Grub menu. When I try to boot Ubuntu, I get a blank screen with a flashing cursor.

## Things I Have Tried So Far

Pressing alt + > switches to text and processess but nothing looks out of the ordinary.(it was stuck on changes.pp was shut down for a while, then moved on to other processes but nothing happened when they ended)

I can also alt+ctrl+f3 and use commands in this state but sudo apt-get update or dpkg doesn't work for some reason. When I try to update, it just gives a fetch error stating it cannot fetch .

I have disabled secure boot but I hadn't done so in my first install. This PC also had Bitlocker but I deleted it because it is a nuisance.

While installing, I had gotten an ACPI BIOS ERROR stating AE ALREADY EXISTS. The internet tells me this is no big deal and is caused by drivers or BIOS but my BIOS is the most recent (not even listed on HP website yet, the website has an older one as most recent) and nomodeset etc. does not work for me. I think I might downgrade BIOS if this keeps up.

Also, the only red failure I saw while installing was "failed to fetch cdrom".

I have reinstalled Ubuntu and tried different iso's at least 50 times now because I need it for work. I might be going crazy with the amount of USB boots and restarts I have done.

nomodeset and downloading from secure graphics did not work for me. Recovery mode dpkg does nothing, and tweaking kernel settings didn't do anything for me as well.

While booting, I see the HP Victus logo splash screen before getting stuck on flashing cursor but it **doesn't have the Ubuntu logo beneath it.** (also it's all black and not purple)

I tried changing everything in my UEFI settings too yet no avail.

Could anybody please help me? thank you

I am creating a new question since my case in unique as opposed to the other flashing cursor problems that are fixed by nomodeset.

Comment: I might as well install Pop_OS or Mint

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix!

Make sure your computer is connected to a network via Ethernet and download/ fix  broken packages using recovery mode (and select "download updates while installing Ubuntu" if reinstalling)